# Cannot connect to an exchange in rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp

I'm trying to achieve something very simple - connect to a RabbitMQ exchange and consume messages. I'm using https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp. Here's the NodeJS code.

```
var rabbitMQ = amqp.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost'
});

rabbitMQ.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Connected to RabbitMQ');
    var exchange = rabbitMQ.exchange('foobar');

    // some more logic
});
```

However, when I run the server, the line `console.log('Connected to RabbitMQ')` gets executed repeatedly forever. Of course, this behavior disappears when I remove `var exchange = connection.exchange('foobar')`.

I'm fairly new to NodeJS, and I've tried reading up the docs and Googling around for example code, but nothing works. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `connection`, you haven't defined a variable called that? I think you mean `var exchange = rabbitMQ.exchange('foobar');`

Comment: @MattHarrison Apologies. It was a typo. :)

Comment: Is that all of the code? Tried it myself and it works fine. I'm thinking there's something else going on with your code.

Comment: I'm actually using socket-io + rabbitmq. Actually, when I am trying to connect to an exchange that does not exist, it works fine. But when I connect to an exchange that already exists, it repeats infinitely.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat infinitely"? In RabbitMQ you don't connect to Exchanges, you connect to the broker and the declare exchanges. More details here http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

Comment: The infinite repeat indicates an error with the connection (very annoying feature of node-amqp). Either it can't connect at all, or there is an error in your code.